# backbone.js fetch is not updating the model

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, fetch-api

I have read other posts here and it looks like most of the time this boils down to fetch being async.  I don't think that is my problem because 1. I test the results in the success callback of fetch and 2.  I can `console.log(model.toJSON())` in the js console later and it still is not updated

Notes:  I am getting a good JSON response from the API and I can get the data by putting 'parse' in my model declaration like so

```
parse: function(data){
    alert(data.screenname);
}
```

Here is my code, why is the model not being updated with the fetch call

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/components/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa("username" + ":" + "password"));
  }
});

var User=Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(data){
    alert(data.screenname);
  },
  urlRoot: 'http://api.myapi.com/user'
});

var user=new User({id:'1'});

user.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response, options){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(user.toJSON());
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I log response, it show a good json coming back, but user.toJSON just shows the id as 1.

I can use `parse` in the model declaration to manually assign each value in the model from the response, but that seems like a dumb way to do it.  I was under the impression that `fetch()` was supposed to populate the model with the result from the server.

******UPDATED******
Here is the response I get back from the server

> {"id":1,"email":"test@email.com","password":"pass","screenname":"myname","id_zipcode":1,"id_city":1,"date_created":"2014-12-25 12:12:12"}

Here are the response headers from my API:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 18:31:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.6 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.6
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=pj1hm0c2ubgaerht3i5losga4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 139
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Can you include the response that comes back from the server

Comment: @kay.one, I added the response I get from the server

Comment: You know you have to put `return data;` in your override of `parse`, right?

Comment: @McGarnagle, I didn't know I had to override parse to get data into the model from `fetch()`.  I am new to backbone, can you expound upon that.  Maybe an example of what you mean about the `return data`.  Thanks

Comment: You don't have to override parse -- I just mean that, if you do, the function has to return the attributes contained in `data`.

Comment: @McGarnagle, thanks but for my simple interaction I don't want to override parse.  I thought that fetch() would take the values from the returned json and just create model attributes from them.  This isn't a real project.  I am just doing it to learn, so I really want to get `fetch()` to load the model up.

Comment: Yes, it should create the model attributes, as you say.  Something else must be the problem.  Can you post the other parts of your code, or better yet, a Fiddle demo?

Comment: @McGarnagle, I just updated the code in my post to show the entire code.  The only other stuff that was on the page was the includes for jquery, underscore, and backbone.  This was really just meant to be a simple test to learn some backbone, but I can get past this part.  I am banging my head because I feel like I am missing something really simple because I haven't found anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: Looks like your example is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/2n9VY/2/

Comment: @McGarnagle, thanks for the help.  I looked at the fiddle and the difference was I had the `parse` in my User model definition in my code that was not in the working fiddle.  Once I took that out it my code worked as expected.  I'm not clear on why the parse was causing problems, but thanks again for the help and the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overridden your `parse()` method to effectively do nothing. It should return all the attributes to set on your model; you have not returned anything, hence, nothing was being set on the model.

It should look like this.

```
var User=Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(data){
    alert(data.screenname);
    return data; //all attributes in data will be set on the model
  },
  urlRoot: 'http://api.myapi.com/user'
});
```